# Kotlin/JS: Check if T is Enum

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-js, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I want to check if a given (reified) generic class is an enum:

`console.log(isEnum<String>(), isEnum<MyObject>(), isEnum<MyEnum>())`
should print `false, false, true` for following classes:

```
enum class MyEnum { ONE, TWO, THREE }
class MyObject(val value: String)
```

Is there a way to write the `isEnum()` function in Kotlin/JS?
The following code does not work and would just return `false false false`:

```
inline fun<reified T: Any> isEnum(): Boolean {
  return T::class.isInstance(Enum)
}
```

Comment: `T::class.js.toString().contains("Enum.call(this")` would work (both for the legacy and the IR compiiler), but i guess this is not the way how to write it .

Comment: Is [kotlin-reflect](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) available for kotlin-js? If you can add this dependency to your project, then try to do `T::class.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)`. It returns `false false true` for me on jvm.

Answer (score -1):

Add dependency on [kotlin-reflect](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) to your project:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:[kotlin version]")
}
```

Then you can use [`isSubclassOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-subclass-of.html) to implement your function:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> isEnum(): Boolean =
    T::class.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)
```

But I'm not sure it will work for kotlin-js. I've tested on jvm only.

Comment: This solution does not work with Kotlin/JS. isSubclassOf() is not available on T::class.